# How to load sys.config from remote boot server

Tags: erlang

I loaded an application from remote boot_server, the beam files are loaded correctly, but the sys.config didn't load.

My start command is: `erl -name bar@127.0.0.1 -loader inet -hosts 127.0.0.1 -id foo -setcookie abc -init_debug -emu_args -boot "/data/gateway/releases/0.1.0/gateway"`

The Boot Server is started by command `erl_boot_server:start([{127,0,0,1}]).` in local host.

How can I load the `sys.config` file correctly?

Comment: you need to use -config flag